# How to define a variable at converge time in Chef?

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe

This might look like yet another question about modifying Chef's behavior at converge time, but I haven't found a solution to this case in any documentation nor other questions.

One of my cookbooks has this definition inside a recipe:

**Cookbook**: A, **recipe**: a

```
node['cookbookA']['resource'].each do |name, options|                                 
  template "/etc/.../#{name}.conf" do                                 
    ...
  end
end
```

This recipe is included from a different recipe in a different cookbook, and a value for `node['cookbookA']['resource']` is defined inside:

**Cookbook**: B, **recipe**: b

```
include_recipe 'A::a'

node.default['cookbookA']['resource'] = ['foo']
```

At execution time, `node['cookbookA']['resource']` is empty.

### What I tried

- I tried finding a way to define the attribute as `lazy`, but it can't be used in this case as it's not a parameter to a resource, but a variable itself.
- [This question](https://gist.github.com/arangamani/4659646) seemed quite exciting, but in this case I think it can't be used as this method modifies an already existing resource, but in this case the attribute is empty so no `template` is created (no loop iteration is made).
- Placing the `include_recipe` statement after defining the attributes, no effect.
- Declaring the precedence as `node.override`, no luck.

## Question

How can this case be solved, so recipe `A::a` has the value defined inside `B::b` at converge time without defining the value of the attribute inside `attributes`, since it is recipe-dependent?

Comment: Two things: you're using `node.default` in a recipe?  If you want to set the attribute, use `node.set[...]` or set the default in an attributes file.  Second: you're setting `node['cookbookA']['resource']` to a string, but then you're trying to iterate as though it's an array.  That will throw an exception.

Comment: 1. Just tried with `node.set`, same result unfortunately. I can't set this in attributes since this is recipe-dependent (I want to set the attribute only if the recipe is included) 2. Yep, my bad, actually I'm passing it an array but I used the `foo` string to ilustrate the example. I changed it in my question.

Comment: Now move the `node.set[...]` line above the `include_recipe`.

Comment: @KarenB Thanks, that worked. If you wish, please add an answer with your tip and I'll accept it as it solved my problem.

Comment: @KarenB There's no problem using `node.default` in a recipe, this give the same behavior as `default` in an attribute file, using `node.set` should be used carefully as it writes the attribute permanently on the node object (removing the recipe from the runlist won't remove the attribute value).

Comment: @nKn If you charge this value from multiple recipes, initialize it as empty array in cookbookA attribute file and then use `node.default['key'] << 'value'` to add a new value at end of the array without overwriting it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The new attribute value needs to be set, by whatever method, before invoking `include_recipe` for the recipe that uses the attribute.